# Why does recompressing a file using gzip produces a different output?

Tags: python, compression, gzip

I need to decompress, edit, and then recompress a Minecraft .dat file. However after recompression the file changes significantly (without any editing on my side) which makes it unreadable for the game.

Here's the snippet of code I use to decompress,

```
import gzip
import shutil
with gzip.open('file_1.dat', 'rb') as f_in:
    with open('file_1.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

and here's the code I use to compress the file:

```
with open('file_1.txt', 'rb') as f_in2:
    with gzip.open('file_1_recmp.dat', 'wb') as f_out2:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in2, f_out2)
```

Here are the [before and after files](https://filebin.net/ppgfoqh8iw7r3ld6).

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the inputs are different, the outputs will be too.  That shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: But the inputs are the same (I didn't edit the file before recompressing it, I just decompressed and then compressed again to see if it stays the same).

Comment: How was `file_1.dat` produced?

Comment: Sorry but how to set the magic id? I'm new to working with gzip and a quick Google search doesn't yield anything useful.

Comment: One problem is that your compressed file contains some extra optional headers which the original data doesn't have. Also don't worry about the files being exactly the same, the  gzip format is standard, the implementation however not necessarily java's could be different but it should have no problem since it follows the same standard

Comment: file_1.dat is a map file that was produced in-game using the "empty map" item @MarkRansom .

Comment: @Teh I will try to remove the optional headers maybe that will help. I wouldn't be worried about the files being diffrent but the difference somehow makes the recompressed file to be unreadable by the game.

Comment: You need to provide links to download the binary files in question. A hex screen dump is entirely useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can never be expected or relied upon that decompressing and recompressing will produce the same result. Different compression code, different versions of that same code, or different compression settings can all give a different result. The only guarantee offered by a lossless compressor is the opposite order, i.e. if you compress and then decompress you get exactly what you started with.

In your case, the question is what is making it "unreadable for the game".

*Update given binary files:*

The before and after gzip files are both valid, and have the same uncompressed data.

The main difference between the before and after is that the header of the after has a file name and some other information in the header. My first theory would be that the decompressor in the game is not compliant with standard gzip headers, and is doing something simplistic and wrong like just skipping the first ten bytes, expecting what follows to be the deflate compressed data.

You can use `gzip.GzipFile` instead of `gzip.open` to control the contents of the header, leaving the file name blank. You can also set the modification time to zero, as it is in the original header. Simple example:

```
import sys
import gzip
f = open('out.gz', 'wb')
gz = gzip.GzipFile('', 'wb', 9, f, 0.)
gz.write('this is a test')
gz.close()
f.close()
```

(Or for Python 3, `gz.write(b'this is a test')`.)

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure the file decompressed without an error, the structure of the [decompressed file](https://pastebin.com/ZaXBS5tz) matches that described on the [MC wikipage](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Map_item_format#map_.3C.23.3E.dat_format). Also [here is the file before decompression](https://pastebin.com/2TJDrxcZ) and here's the [output file after recompression](https://pastebin.com/sSfJd13Q) . Thanks for the anwser!

Comment: I'm not asking if your decompression of the original file worked. I'm asking if you decompressed the _recompressed_ file.

Comment: Both files you attempted to link are hopelessly messed up. They have no correlation to your hex dumps. Did you try to print the files and then copy and paste the result? You cannot print binary data.

Comment: Decompressing the recompressed file produces the same result as decompressing the original file. As to the hex files, sorry for sending garbage data, here's [the link](https://filebin.net/ppgfoqh8iw7r3ld6) to the original and recompressed files . I hope it works this time, and thanks for the anwsers!

Comment: Thanks. That's much better. There was something wrong with the recompressed hex dump you originally posted, since what was there would have never gotten past the header to decompress the data.

Comment: I just removed the headers and it works! Thanks for your help!